# TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have been using the scikit-learn library. I'm trying to use the Gaussian Naive Bayes Module under the scikit-learn library but I'm running into the following error. TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Below is the code snippet.

```
training = GaussianNB()
training = training.fit(trainData, target)
prediction = training.predict(testData)
```

This is target

```
['ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML', 'AML']
```

This is trainData

```
[['-214' '-153' '-58' ..., '36' '191' '-37']
['-139' '-73' '-1' ..., '11' '76' '-14']
['-76' '-49' '-307' ..., '41' '228' '-41']
..., 
['-32' '-49' '49' ..., '-26' '133' '-32']
['-124' '-79' '-37' ..., '39' '298' '-3']
['-135' '-186' '-70' ..., '-12' '790' '-10']]
```

Below is the stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prediction.py", line 90, in <module>
  gaussianNaiveBayes()
File "prediction.py", line 76, in gaussianNaiveBayes
  training = training.fit(trainData, target)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 163, in fit
  self.theta_[i, :] = np.mean(Xi, axis=0)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/ core/fromnumeric.py", line 2716, in mean
  out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 62, in _mean
  ret = um.add.reduce(arr, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Answer (score 171):

It looks like your 'trainData' is a list of strings:

```
['-214' '-153' '-58' ..., '36' '191' '-37']
```

Change your 'trainData' to a numeric type.

```
 import numpy as np
 np.array(['1','2','3']).astype(np.float)
```

Comment: @JAB why we need numeric type data?

Comment: @RohitChopra is your question, why can't you do maths on strings? Or, why doesn't numpy do the conversion under the covers?

Comment: @JAB Numpy appears to refuse to do any numerical operations on recarrays, irrespective of the dtype, as you can tell by trying it on one of their doctstring examples.
`x = np.core.records.fromrecords([(1.3,1.2),(2.1,1.3)], names='col1,col2'); x.sum()`

Answer (score 4):

When your are trying to apply prod on string type of value like:

```
['-214' '-153' '-58' ..., '36' '191' '-37']
```

you will get the error.

Solution:
Append only integer value like `[1,2,3]`, and you will get your expected output.

If the value is in string format before appending then, in the array you can convert the type into `int` type and store it in a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice facing that error. Typically you have to check the type compatibility of your data. Take few minutes to check it, print it and you should find an incompatibility.