# Type of data allowed in features list in sklearn ?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Guys I am trying to use sklearn (or scikit-learn) library for machine learning but I am again and again running into an error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

My code lines where error is occuring is:

```
X=[['SALES',2,4],['SALES',3,1],['TECHNICAL',9,1]];
Y=['NICE','NOT NICE','AWESOME']
classifier.fit(np.array(X),np.array(Y))
```

and if I convert the 'SALES' and 'TECHNICAL' categorical values to numbers like 0 and 1 then it works just fine.

```
X=[[0,2,4],[0,3,1],[1,9,1]];
Y=['NICE','NOT NICE','AWESOME']
classifier.fit(np.array(X),np.array(Y))
```

My question is do I have to convert all the categorical values of string type in to numbers in features list? I know this might be a very stupid question but just help me out ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393103/typeerror-cannot-perform-reduce-with-flexible-type

Comment: Thanks @hellpanderrr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input to `scikit-learn` estimation models must always be numeric numpy arrays.

So yes, you have to convert categorical string features to numbers (either ordinal or dummyfication) before feedding them to sklearn.