# mean of large list with np.mean

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a list with more than 10000 number in it and `np.mean()` does not work for this many (it works till 2000 numbers) 
what  should I do?

I put this code: `np.sum(myList])`

and I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-50e215357de3> in <module>
----> 1 np.sum(cleanedList[1:20000])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)
   2074 
   2075     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
-> 2076                           initial=initial)
   2077 
   2078 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     84                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     85 
---> 86     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     87 
     88 

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Comment: isn't it : `myList.sum()/len(myList)`

Comment: "np.mean does not work for this many". I can call `np.mean` on 20 million numbers in an instant: `np.random.random(20_000_000).mean()` so I would suspect that your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What is `type(cleanedList[n])` where you should find `n` by doing a binary search to figure out when it stops working? My guess is that you've got something in there that is not a number.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393103/typeerror-cannot-perform-reduce-with-flexible-type

Comment: no sum doesnot work for this many too

Comment: no all the numbers are fine cause i can get np.mean in each 2000 number

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducer so we can actually see what you are doing. `numpy.mean()` can definitely handle big lists of numbers (its what `numpy` is designed for). "Guess the bug" is a waste of everyone's time ...

Comment: The `flexible type` error has nothing to do with the size of the input list.  It's about the `dtype`, once the list is converted to an array, `np.array(alist)`.  That array should be numeric for `sum` to work.  If strings or something else it will raise this error.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error it is probable that your input list is a list of strings that happen to represent numbers. Actually convert your inputs into a list of floats and then `numpy.mean()` will work just fine.

Comment: I can not convert it to float and i get " could not convert string to float: " error

Comment: If you can't convert an entry to a number, how do you expect to be able to take a mean using it?