# Cannot perform reduce with flexible type in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to implement a sklearn pipeline, my code is as follows. It's tips dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/tipping I'm trying to labelencode binary features, one hot encode day column and scale the total column. Below you can find one of my classes (the other two have almost the same structure so I won't post them, I get same error as I get with this one)

```
class onehotencode(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

  def __init__(self, column=None):
    for column in cols_to_encode:
        self.column = column

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, X):
    encoder = OneHotEncoder()
    return encoder.fit_transform(X[self.column])
class labelencode(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

  def __init__(self, column = None):
    for column in cols_to_encode_label:
        self.column = column

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, X):
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    return encoder.fit_transform(X[self.column])

pipeline = Pipeline([('ohe',onehotencode()),
                    ('le',labelencode()),
                    ('scaler',scaler())])
df_transformed = pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

When I try to fit to pipeline I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I tried to change the transform as follows:

```
def transform(self, X):
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    return encoder.fit_transform(X[[self.column]])
```

When I do I get following error:

```
cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Can anyone help me? I really did search for above errors and couldn't fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: could you edit the question and add the result of `df.head()` inside the question?

Comment: instead I've given the link to dataset itself.

Comment: What are the values of `cols_to_encode` and `cols_to_encode_label`?

Comment: target = df['tip']
cols_to_scale = ['total_bill','size']
cols_to_encode = ['day']
cols_to_encode_label = ['sex', 'smoker', 'time']

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393103/typeerror-cannot-perform-reduce-with-flexible-type

Comment: @UtkuKAYNAR no it isn't, in the link you've sent the error occurs because the person tried to fit data that wasn't preprocessed properly. my problem is the preprocessing itself, I'm not trying to fit the data to an estimator, I'm not there yet. This error occurs during the preprocessing. I'm already trying to encode the strings so. I've fixed above error by using a workaround but I still wonder why it popped up.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem that I observed was the init method in class:

```
  def __init__(self, column=None):
      for column in cols_to_encode:
          self.column = column
```

As I understand, you are trying to assign a list for columns to encode but the loop is not necessary there (for both encoders), you can simply assign the list as:

```
  def __init__(self, columns):
      self.columns = columns
```

For one hot encoder I think pd.get_dummies() is more elegant rather than OneHotEncoder, so the transform function will be:

```
    def transform(self, X):
        '''
        1.Copy the information from original df, 
        2.Drop the old column from new df, 
        3.Return the new df with one hot encoded columns'''
        new_df = X.copy(deep=True)
        new_df.drop(self._cols_one_hot,axis=1,inplace=True)
        return new_df.join(pd.get_dummies(X[self._cols_one_hot]))
```

For label encoder part, it will not work for multiple columns because LabelEncoder does not support multiple columns encoding. So you have to visit and encode for each column.

```
    def transform(self, X):
     '''
        1.Copy the information from original df, 
        2.Label encode the columns,
        3.Drop the old columns, 
        4.Return the new df with label encoded columns'''
        new_df = X.copy(deep=True)
        label_encoded_cols =  new_df[self._cols_label_encode].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
        new_df.drop(self._cols_label_encode,axis=1,inplace=True)
        return new_df.join(label_encoded_cols)
```

Final solution will be:

```
class onehotencode(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, cols_one_hot):
        self._cols_one_hot = cols_one_hot

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        '''
        1.Copy the information from original df, 
        2.Drop the old column from new df, 
        3.Return the new df with one hot encoded columns
        '''
        new_df = X.copy(deep=True)
        new_df.drop(self._cols_one_hot,axis=1,inplace=True)
        return new_df.join(pd.get_dummies(X[self._cols_one_hot]))


class labelencode(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, cols_label_encode):
        self._cols_label_encode = cols_label_encode

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        '''
        1.Copy the information from original df, 
        2.Label encode the columns,
        3.Drop the old columns, 
        4.Return the new df with label encoded columns
        '''
        new_df = X.copy(deep=True)
        label_encoded_cols = new_df[self._cols_label_encode].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
        new_df.drop(self._cols_label_encode,axis=1,inplace=True)
        return new_df.join(label_encoded_cols)
```

Then the pipeline will be called as:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('ohe',onehotencode(cols_to_encode)),
                    ('le',labelencode(cols_to_encode_label))])

df_transformed = pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

df_transformed.head() will print:

[image: df_transformed.head()]