# while and function with unsuported operator in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm attempting to make a function to remove data with z values  > than 3 in a list, for this I'm using 'while' because after remove that values in the old list, z values > 3 in the new list can appear again. Then, this loop should be made until z <= 3.

The error is: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Code

```
import numpy as np

def removeout(lista):
    from scipy import stats
    from numpy import abs
    a = []
    z = abs(stats.zscore(lista))
    while any(i > 3 for i in z):


        for i, n in zip(lista, z):

            if i is 'Nan':
                a.append('Nan')
                continue
            elif n <= 3:
                b = i
            elif n > 3:
                b = 'Nan'

            a.append(b)

        lista = a.copy()
        z = abs(stats.zscore(lista))

    return lista


list1 = np.random.normal(500, 100, 1000)
new_list = removeout(list1)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error shows you in which line you have problem - so use `print()` and print(type(..))` to see values in variables which you use in this line. And check in documentation what values expect functions used in this line. It seems `zscore` expects something different then `numpy.array`

Comment: Google search of the error yields this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393103/typeerror-cannot-perform-reduce-with-flexible-type . The probelms is the 'nan' which is a string. Try None or np.nan.

Comment: code works for me when I generate smaller list - i.e. `np.random.normal(500, 100, 10)` or I generate big list but using `np.random.rand`

Comment: Hey OP, numpy has an amazing masking system that allows you to get rid of those values superior to three directly like so: `X = X[X <= 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem makes

```
    lista = a.copy()
```

because `a` is normal list but original `lista` was `numpy.ndarray` and later `stats.zscore()` has problem to work with this list.

You have to create `numpy.array`.

And it needs data type `float`, `np.float` or `"float64"` (at least on my computer).

```
    lista = np.array(a).astype('float64')
```

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def removeout(lista):
    a = []

    #print('[DEBUG] first')
    #print('[DEBUG]', type(lista), lista.dtype)

    z = np.abs(stats.zscore(lista))

    while any(i > 3 for i in z):


        for i, n in zip(lista, z):

            if i is 'Nan':
                a.append('Nan')
                continue
            elif n <= 3:
                b = i
            elif n > 3:
                b = 'Nan'

            a.append(b)

        lista = np.array(a).astype('float64')

        #print('[DEBUG] second')
        #print('[DEBUG]', type(lista), lista.dtype)

        z = np.abs(stats.zscore(lista))

    return lista

list1 = np.random.normal(500, 100, 1000)
#print('[DEBUG] start')
#print('[DEBUG]', type(list1), list1.dtype)

new_list = removeout(list1)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like type casting is needed so that they type is not flexible 
below is the updated code ... pls check

```
import numpy as np

def removeout(lista):
    from scipy import stats
    from numpy import abs
    a = []
    z = abs(stats.zscore(lista.astype(np.float)))
    while any(i > 3 for i in z):


        for i, n in zip(lista, z):

            if i is 'Nan':
                a.append('Nan')
                continue
            elif n <= 3:
                b = i
            elif n > 3:
                b = 'Nan'

            a.append(b)

        lista = np.array(a.copy())
        z = abs(stats.zscore(lista.astype(np.float)))

    return lista


list1 = np.random.normal(500, 100, 1000)
new_list = removeout(list1)
print(new_list)
```