# How do I run multiple functions on my aggregated pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, aggregate

I have the following data for wind speed and wind direction taken over the course of a month in Salt Lake City.  I want to group by the hour data were taken.  For the data taken within that hour, I want to accomplish two things: (1) calculate mean wind speed (2) apply a function I have defined ("yamatrino") to all the wind_direction measurements taken within each hour.

```
        time                     Station_ID  wind_speed  wind_direction
    0   2019-08-01 00:00:00 UTC  WBB         3.48        96.1
    1   2019-08-01 00:00:00 UTC  UT215       6.54        141.4
    2   2019-08-01 00:00:00 UTC  MTMET       3.39        67.75
    3   2019-08-01 00:00:00 UTC  NAA         5.99        154.9
    4   2019-08-01 00:00:00 UTC  QHW         1.52        107
```

Below is the code I have written to (1) convert time data into a datetime format and (2) to create two columns with the mean wind speeds and yamatrino values for each hour of data.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC')

df.groupby(df['time'].dt.hour)['wind_direction', 'wind_speed'].agg([('yamatrino_value', lambda wind_direction: yamatrino(wind_direction)), ('hourly_velocity_mean', np.mean('wind_speed'))])
```

The error reads "TYPE ERROR: cannot perform reduce with flexible type"
I am confused how to aggregate with more than one column of data.

Comment: Can you check the data type first, seems like your error point to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28396902/9243482)

Comment: What is `hourly_velocity_mean`? A method or column in data?

Comment: @Parfait it is the name of a column I would like to make.  It is the time-averaged wind speed (one average for every hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a dictionary inside [**`DataFrame.groupby.agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) call to run separate aggregate functions on separate columns. And if your method expects one parameter, `lambda` is not needed.

```
df.groupby(df['time'].dt.hour).agg({'wind_direction': yamatrino, 
                                    'wind_speed': np.mean})
```

And as of v0.25.0+, you can [name aggregate columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-aggregate-named) which may be what you intended with *yamatrino_value* and *hourly_velocity_mean* . However, you need to use named tuples with fields: `['column', 'aggfunc']`.

```
df.groupby(df['time'].dt.hour).agg(yamatrino_value = ('wind_direction', yamatrino), 
                                   hourly_velocity_mean = ('wind_speed', np.mean))
```